# Person who is decided on, acted on, judged, voted on, or is reviewed

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word or words for a person who is being analyzed, judged, or reviewed, and a matching word for the person doing the reviewing, judging, or analyzing. Preferably the words would be somewhat generalized.

For instance, there is a reviewer, analyzer, or judge, but I can't think of any specific words for the person on the receiving end.

More generally for the person being acted on there is "subject", or "target", but I can't think of anything that generally describes the person reviewing the other person other than "actor".

Comment: Kinda depends on the circumstances, but "nominee" would work in many cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reviewee

> A person who is subjected to a review.

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reviewee)

Also, a

*contestant*

or an

*entrant*

is often subject to review, analysis, judgement.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context but maybe one of these would work:

candidate ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candidate))

> a : one that aspires to or is nominated or qualified for an office, membership, or award a candidate for governor a candidate for "Manager of the Year" the best candidate for the job

defendant ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defendant))

> a person or group against whom a criminal or civil action is brought :  someone who is being sued or accused of committing a crime if the jury finds the defendant not guilty — compare